# Is it possible to always get the optimal formula regardless of the derivation method?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, intuition, problem-solving

Today I've tried to solve a geometric problem (collision point between two circles in a specific situation). I found a working solution but I'm not sure if it was optimal (maybe my solution took more calculations and work than necessary to get the result).

The solution took some known data (circles' positions and radii, and other stuff), calculated a few half-products (circle's new center point after moving along a vector and so on...) and finally calculated the searched collision point.

This was needed for a computer program so it needed to be all brought down to formulas. Some formulas took known data and calculated the half-products, the other(s) took half-products and calculated the final result. So it's possible to combine all these formulas into one big one which takes the known starting data and calculated the final result. Is that correct (in the general case)?

And if my big formula took only a few known data (a few variables) and used them in multiple places then the formula could be reduces/simplified, e.g.:

```
x^2 + 64x - y - 32x + 3y -> x * (x + 32) + 2y
```

So my question is: if my solution is **correct** (regardless of how complicated/unoptimal way it is to calculate the result) and I can bring it all down to **1 formula** which only uses the starting variables and then I **maximally reduce/simplify that formula** - will I **always** (in any case) get **the optimal formula/way to calculate the final result**? Regardless of the method (way of getting to the result)?

**EDIT:** After thinking about my question I think I could state it differently:
Let's say my solution is correct (i.e. produces the correct result) and let's say I can bring it down to a single formula. If I use different approaches I would probably get different formulas. But are they all equivalent (can I always transform one into another)? Can I reduce every such formula to the same form (regardless of its optimality)?

Comment: "Optimal" is not even well-defined here. For example, if you're looking at practical efficiency on a computer, different chips (or compilers) may perform better on different forms of the formula.

Comment: Well, that's true. But even despite that there are still algorithms and solutions that are generally considered optimal or at least better than others. I hope what you pointed out doesn't invalidate my whole question.

Answer (score 0):

Defining "*maximally reduce*" to be the simplest way to write down a function, and "*optimal formula*" to be the calculation method that takes the least amount of time, reduction is **not** guaranteed to find the most efficient method.

Here's a quick counterexample. Let's say I have a computer that takes 1 second to multiply two numbers, and 0.1 seconds to add two numbers. Now I have two functions,
$$f(x) = 5x$$
$$g(x) = x + x + x + x + x$$
It looks like $f$ is much simpler! But that computation will take 1 second, while $g$ will take only half that time.

This seems like a pretty ridiculous scenario, but floating point multiplication was once pretty slow! A more relevant example is the [Discrete Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) (DFT). The mathematical description is quite simple, but there are [complicated ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) of doing the transform much more quickly. Mathematical notation is not directly related to computational efficiency!

Comment: What you wrote is true but that's not exactly what I meant in my question. Please see the edit I've added.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "optimal", if we're not in the context of computing. Functions are defined by input and output pairs--if two well-defined functions always produce the same output given the same input, they are identical.

Comment: After thinking about my question I stated it differently (hopefully now it's precise and unambiguous). Please see the edit to my question.

Comment: I feel like you've considerably changed the meaning of this question through the edits, and it might be helpful to re-ask this question with just the last paragraph. In particular, I would avoid using the words "optimal" and "simplify", since they are not related to what you're really asking!

Comment: After thinking about this for a bit, I actually really like this question. It's a bit hard to form, but I might suggest rephrasing it slightly differently: suppose f(x) = g(x) for all real x, and both f and g are sufficiently nice (perhaps we might limit them to be polynomials or analytic functions). Can we manipulate one (with algebraic transformations) into the other?

Comment: Ok, I will re-ask the question. What about this thread, though? Should I delete it? Or leave it as it is? As for the "optimality of formula" - all I meant was that however I define it, if I can always transform one formula into another then I can transform any crappy (unoptimal) formula into an optimal one.

Comment: I've posted the question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715518/is-it-always-possible-to-transform-one-function-into-another As I wasn't sure what range of functions or I should mention I just quoted you, I hope you don't mind.